# Export status change date odoo 8

Tags: export, odoo, odoo-8

I want to know if I can extract status change date of an object without create a field for that.
For example when passing from nouveau to actif state:

```
state = fields.Selection([
    ('nouveau','Nouveau'),
    ('actif','Actif'),
    ('expired','Expiré'),
],string="Etat", default="nouveau")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi first you need to enable track visibility on for status field. then if you change any status from you can see all track with timestamp.

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean but I need an extract of satus change date of existing object

Comment: Is that possible or not ?

Comment: Yes possible. You can read data from track visiblity with timestamp and user wise. from Settings=>Database Structure=>Tracking Values (mail.tracking.value)

Comment: if you get your answer please upvote my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible. You could know the last modification of your record with value. write_date.